# How to restore a user on my pc?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

I just unchecked "Users must enter a user name and a password to use this computer" in User accounts accessed by Running control passwords2 and it deleted all of my other user accounts. Why is that?

The good thing is that I still have all files from these users. If I create another user, I know I won't be able to completely delete those files without reformatting and reinstalling Windows.

So, is there a way to recover those user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a restoring point than you can try restoring the whole computer to the time when you had those user accounts.

```
Control Panel>System and Security>Backup and Restore>Restore the computer setting>Open system restore.
```