# How to recover deleted user account

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, users

I accidentally deleted my main user account “blaze” and I used it with everything. All my files were on it. I did this command (or something similar) while I was logged in as admin:

```
net user blaze /delete
```

I didn’t mean to do that command. How do I reverse it? All the files from “blaze” are still in the user folder, so I’m happy I still have all my stuff. But how do I reverse what I did so I can log in as blaze again?

Comment: You mention AD in your question. What OS is your DC running? What are your Forest and Domain functional levels? Is the AD Recycle Bin enabled, if applicable? Your answers to these questions will determine how and by which methods and tools you can recover/restore the deleted user account.

Comment: I’m running Windows 10 recycle bin is enabled, but I still have the user file how do I just make it so I can use that user file as a account and log into it??

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/901869/how-to-restore-a-user-on-my-pc

Answer (score -1):

Solved. Re-created user account.